# Create report to get Stage conversion rate of opportunity

Tags: reporting, opportunity, business-logic, report-builder

I want to create a report on opportunity object to get conversion rate.
Like if I have 100 opportunities are in 1 stage and 10 of them will travel all the stage and end with close-won So first stage probability would be 10% then let say 50 opportunities are in 2 stage and only 10 will move to close won stage so 2 stage probability would be 20%. Same I want to for each stage. 
I have previous year opportunity history report. How can I get conversion rate for each and every stage in Salesforce.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This report will be an Opportunity History Report. I have a similar report that was built solely for a graph. For mine, I made it a matrix report.

I added the From Stage on the left, and the To Stage on the top. Add a filter that says Stage Change = True. After that, I added my chart. The Y axis was the record Count, the X Axis is From Stage.

Since our Opportunities never skip a stage (at least in our system, as a validation rule has been added to prevent that), each move is from the previous stage to the next stage. So, my chart shows that we have a lot of Opportunities in Stage 1, fewer in 2, even fewer in 3, and so on.

Comment: Can we create funnel instead of chart?

Comment: You should be able to. The funnel is just a graph option when you add the chart.